# How to obtain a class deleted in visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to get a class deleted from Visual Studio 2010?

I just deleted the wrong file, and now there is another one with the same name but empty. 
Is there is a way to obtain the original page ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your trash bin, a file deleted in VS is the same as a file deleted in windows explorer

Comment: thankss, i was review that in other bin... but now i found it